# ¿ Cómo alinear elementos de div?

Tags: css, bootstrap, angular, sass, flexbox

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de prueba con angular, he creado una pequeña barra de navegación pero no consigo que se vea como yo quisiera. Quiero que el icono de favoritos (corazón) este al final de la barra y el input en medio, pero ni intentandolo con flex lo consigo.

Tambien que se vea bien en móvil pero se mueve todo cuando hago la ventana pequeña.

Alguna idea de como poder hacerlo?

Adjunto link del proyecto en StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/github/ralvaradofelix/Angular-Test